# how do I setup the C-Berry TFT Screen with my Pi 2

Tags: screen

How do I setup my C-Berry 5" TFT Screen from Admatec, with my Raspberry Pi 2 Model B?
Distro: Raspbian Jessie 2015-11-21

Tried:

```
wget http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/bcm2835/bcm2835-1.46.tar.gz 
tar zxvf bcm2835-1.xx.tar.gz
cd bcm2835-1.xx
./configure
make
sudo make check
sudo make install
```

Made sure SPI and I2C are off in raspi-config and Tree is on.

```
wget http://admatec.de/sites/default/files/downloads/C-Berry.tar.gz
tar zxvf C-Berry.tar.gz
cd /C-Berry/SW/tft_test
make
sudo ./tft_test
```

Instructions: https://www.elfa.se/Web/Downloads/_t/d/C-BERRY_eng_tds.pdf?mime=application%2Fpdf

BR
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the short answer.... for god's sake look at the connecting cable between screen and TFT add-on card. **Blueish color facing down not up.**

Full stepvise instruction:

Install latest Raspberian distro (in this case Raspbian Jessie 2015-11-21 - 4.1.13-v7+ #826)

Have all the latest by:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then download and unpack BCM2835 package:

```
cd Downloads
wget http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/bcm2835/bcm2835-1.48.tar.gz
tar zxvf bcm2835-1.48.tar.gz
```

Adjust the bcm2835.h to RPi2 settings (how I did):

```
sudo nano bcm2835-1.48/src/bcm2835.h
```

Change row defining:

```
#define BCM2835_PERI_BASE               0x20000000
```

TO:

```
#define BCM2835_PERI_BASE               0x3F000000
```

Compile the library:

```
cd bcm2835-1.48
./configure
make
sudo make check
sudo make install
```

In order for bcm2835 library SPI to work, you may need to disable the SPI kernel module using:

- sudo raspi-config
- under Advanced Options - enable Device Tree under
- Advanced Options - disable SPI
- Reboot.

Then first run your first try with screen developers software:

```
cd Download
wget http://admatec.de/sites/default/files/downloads/C-Berry.tar.gz
tar zxvf C-Berry.tar.gz
cd C-Berry/SW/tft_test
make
sudo ./tft_test
```